# Assigning variables from inputs in FOR loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

For my university python course I have an assignment which asks:

Create a change-counting game that gets the user to enter the number of coins
necessary to make exactly two dollars. Design an algorithm, express it in
pseudocode, and then use it to implement a Python program that prompts the user
to enter a number of 5c coins, 10c coins, 20c coins, 50c coins, $1 coins and
$2 coins. If the total value of those coins entered is equal to two dollars,
then the program should congratulate the user for winning the game. Otherwise
the program should display a message advising that the total was NOT exactly
two dollars, and showing how much the value was above or below two dollars.

I understand how to implement the program but im having trouble trying to apply a variable to the user inputs without repetition.

I would like to use a FOR loop like so:

```
def main():
    for coin in ['5c','10c','20c','50c','$1','$2']:
        int(input("Enter the number of " + coin + " coins you wish use: "))


#Call the main function
 main()
```

But how do I assign a new variable to each user input every time it loops?

Comment: Use list for this. a = [] a.append()

Comment: use a dictionary instead, as the coins are a string

Comment: And you can also present your pseudocode and ask how to map it into Python, for a better and more to-the-point question.

Comment: Also put your python minor version as the tag, or at least `Python 2.x` or `Python 3.x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best would be a list or a dictionary.

```
inputFor= {}
for coin in ['5c','10c','20c','50c','$1','$2']:
    inputFor[coin]= int(input("Enter the number of " + coin + " coins you wish use: "))
```

In the previous case, a dictionary.  Then you can retrieve the user answers in the following way:

```
... inputFor['5c'] ...
... inputFor['10c'] ...
... inputFor['20c'] ...
... inputFor['50c'] ...
... inputFor['$1'] ...
... inputFor['$2'] ...
```

The dots represent the context in which you want to use the answers (formulas, display, etc).

Comment: In python there are both arrays and map, but they mean different things. These you are using are called lists and dictionaries.

Comment: @Antti Haapala  Thanks.  Corrections applied.

Answer (score 1):

```
def main():
    coins = {}
    for kind in ['5c','10c','20c','50c','$1','$2']:
        coins[kind] = int(raw_input("Enter the number of " + kind \
                                 + " coins you wish use: ").strip() or 0)
```